# Align text and images on the same vertical line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have the following markup which uses bootstrap 4:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <img src="~/img/img1.png" style="height:60.3px;width:750px" class="mx-auto d-none d-sm-block" />
            <p  style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">...</p>
            <p  style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">...</p>

            <img src="~/img/img2.png" class="mx-auto d-block" />

            <p  style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">...</p>
            <p  style="color: #2EBDBE;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;margin-bottom: 0px;">...</p>


        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Currently i got this layout:-

[image]

where the images are centered while the text is left aligned, so how i can force the text to have the same vertical alignment as the images?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but edit classes or whatever to make it work on your site:

```html
<div class="container" style="position:relative; display:inline-block;">
  <img class="mx-auto d-none d-sm-block" style="display:block; height:60.3px;width:750px" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131603.jpg">
  <div class="text-box" style="position:relative; height:100%; text-align: center; display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: flex-start; width: 100%;">
    <p class="centeredTxt" style="display: block; color: #333;">Text is centered under image</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-box" style="position:relative; height:100%; text-align: center; display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: flex-start; width: 100%;">
    <p class="centeredTxt" style="display: block; color: #333;">Text is centered under image 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Difficult to understand how this would work in your code as I don't have the complete code, but I edited my answer to better suit your request.

Comment: this worked if the `<p>` contain word that does not span multiple lines, but for long `<p>` this did not have any effect..

Comment: I think you must wrap the image and the `<p>` tags in the same div, as a container, to be able to align them in the center according to that new div. You need help setting this up? I can give you an example.

Comment: if you can setup an example will be great

Comment: Alright. I will edit my code and paste a code I threw together, I haven't used your classnames, because you know better than me what you can/can not discard. But look at how the style for those divs are set up, copy it to your need and you should have a perfectly working div, which is also responsive.

This code would be for 1 image tho, just paste 2 of these and you should be able to style these differently.

Comment: I'll try and implement your code into it, but again I do not have your images and it might not be accurate.

Comment: I did not get your point, your code looks different than mine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216137/discussion-between-r-srour-and-test-test).